# mail settings are not working in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to send mail.
Here are my `development.rb` settings:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 25,
    domain: "mydomain.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    #enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["prem.regmi@braindigit.com "],
    password: ENV[""]
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`ENV` means environment variable. I don't think you have an environment variable called `prem.regmi@braindigit.com`. Try this instead:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 25,
  domain: "mydomain.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  # enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: "prem.regmi@braindigit.com",
  password: ""
}
```

Comment: I am using devise authentication for mail.it doesnot work? any idea?

Comment: What doesn't work?? Any errors? Do you have a mailserver running on 127.0.0.1? Is your username correct? Don't you need a password?

Comment: I understand that. If you cannot give me any other info I cannot help you.

Comment: In my code I am using my password. and my username is also correct but mail is not send. ya mailserver is running in localhost.

Comment: Did you try sending mail with your normal mail client using these settings? Does that work?

Comment: I just try from my terminal as if mail server is working or not In terminal      { $ mail regmiprem101@gmail.com
Cc: 
Subject: what }
and it is working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14503/discussion-between-regmiprem-and-mischa)

Comment: Your local mail is not smtp, see my reply in chat